# How to know when VC2 was dismissed on VC1?

Tags: swift, delegates, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I have ViewController1 that goes to ViewModel and then to Coordinator to present ViewController2.

The problem is: I need to know when VC2 was dismissed on VC1.

What I need to do: When VC2 is dismissed, I need to reload my table from VC1.

I can not use Delegate since I cant communicate between then (because of Coordinator).

Any help please?

Adding some code: My Coordinator:

```
public class Coordinator: CoordinatorProtocol {

public func openVC1() {
    let viewModel = ViewModel1(coordinator: self)
    guard let VC1 = ViewControllerOne.instantiate(storyboard: storyboard, viewModel: viewModel) else {
        return
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
}

public func openVC2() {
    let viewModel = ViewModel2()
    guard let alertPriceDeleteVC = ViewControllerTwo.instantiate(storyboard: storyboard, viewModel: viewModel) else {
        return
    }
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
    navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

CoordinatorProtocol:

```
public protocol CoordinatorProtocol {
    func openVC1()
    func openVC2()
}
```

My ViewModel1 calling VC2 through coordinatorDelegate:

```
func openVC2() {
    coordinator.openVC2()
}
```

What I do when I finish ViewController2 and send user back do VC1:

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Oh, so you ask how to communicate and then _refuse_ to use the most common means of communication? What other restrictions do you impose upon yourself? Are you allowed to use a notification? If the ViewModel is holding the model data, is it permitted for ViewController2 to send changes up to the ViewModel and have the ViewModel send them down to the ViewController1?

Comment: @matt I am not refusing. I just dont know how can I use delegate since both VCs doesnt communicate. Im not allowed to use notifications. I have 2 view models, one for VC1, another to VC2, I dont communicate between them also.

Comment: Well you haven't given any particulars. You've spoken only in generalities, so I've answered only in generalities. You really claim there is no object in your entire universe that ever sees both view controllers at once? There is no segue between them in the storyboard? There is no object that handles routing? I find that very difficult to believe.

Comment: Im not using segues on storyboard. What I do is: from VC1, I go to a method on ViewModel1, calling a coordinatorDelegate to present my VC2. This coordinator delegate was set when I first started VC1. And then I do on Coordinator: navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil). I really dont know how to come back to VC1 to reload my table. Sorry, I dont have too much experience.

Comment: Ok but that suggests that the coordinator delegate has access to both VC1 and VC2 at the same time, so it could configure the protocol-delegate relationship between them. Or, the coordinator delegate _itself_ could serve as the delegate for VC2 and pass the word back to VC1.

Comment: This may help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/175/advanced-coordinator-pattern-tutorial-ios

Comment: Ok Matt, this coordinator delegate has access to both separated methods which I start VC1 and VC2. Even if I put a method on this delegate like "reloadData()". I would connect this delegate it when starting VC2. And then, when dismissing it, it would come back to Coordinator. But I would need to start again VC1, right? I dont know how I will have on coordinator that existent instance from VC1 that is already opened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to assign delegate value from prepare. Or you can assign delegate with initialize RedScreenVC(self) from your ViewController if u don't want to use storyboard/xib.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool) {
        print("text: \(text) isShown: \(isShown)")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "RedScreenVC") {
            let redScreenVC = segue.destination as? RedScreenVC
            redScreenVC?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextPageButtonEventLustener(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "RedScreenVC", sender: sender)
    }
}



import UIKit

protocol NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool)
}
class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: NavDelegate?

    var redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))

    var navigateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 350, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Navigate", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonAction(){
        if self.redView.backgroundColor == .gray {
            self.redView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        }
    self.delegate.navigate(text:"", isShown: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        delegate.navigate(text: "Navigation Success", isShown: true)

        view.addSubview(redView)

        view.addSubview(navigateButton)
    }

}
```

If you do not want to use storyboard.

```
let redScreenVC = RedScreenVC()

redScreenVC.delegate = self

    class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {
      override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        self.view.backgroundColor=CustomColor.PAGE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_1
        //From here you need to create your email and password textfield
    }
}
```